# How to reserve screen space in OS X?

Tags: macos, window, size, screen, limit

In OSX, Dock when visible, reserves space that other windows can't use. How's that done?

In my use case,

1. I want to limit the space in which all application windows can open,
2. Whenever a new popup comes up it should be confined within the limited space and centred relative to the limited space
3. Something like [Desktop Coral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/) for windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an apple script, which continuously monitors which application is started and resizes it to the desired size on launch. Small example to do so is given in following script:

https://gist.github.com/akshay-bhardwaj/daf93c2e1ed8b79a4619

Hope this helps. If you have further issues please feel free to ask

Regards

Comment: updated the question for more clarity, sorry this isn't helpful